# Spring Android Twitter Callback URL

Tags: java, android, twitter-oauth, spring-social-twitter, spring-android

I need to implement an OAuth login in my Android application using the Twitter API. I found a great project on GitHub ([spring-android-samples](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-android-samples/tree/master/spring-android-twitter-client)) with a very good example, but I have a problem with respect to the parameter "Callback URL".

When I submit my login and password, my android application opens a browser instance (with callback URL) rather than processing the response in the background:

[image]

Has anyone had to implement something similar and could help me please? 
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't actually have to register the `x-android-org-springsource-twitterclient://twitter-oauth-response` URL with the Twitter app settings. In fact, the callback URL configured on Twitter doesn't really matter in this case. The callback URL is sent to Twitter within the request to fetch the OAuth request token.

Note that within the `AndroidManifest.xml` there is a specified `<intent-filter>` for the `TwitterWebOAuthActivity` which configures this callback URL. This filter tells Android to redirect requests to the activity.

```
<activity
    android:name=".TwitterWebOAuthActivity"
    android:excludeFromRecents="true"
    android:noHistory="true" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

        <data
            android:host="twitter-oauth-response"
            android:scheme="x-org-springsource-android-twitterclient" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Note also in `res/values/connect_settings.xml` the `twitter_oauth_callback_url` string is again configured.

```
<string name="twitter_oauth_callback_url">x-org-springsource-android-twitterclient://twitter-oauth-response</string>
```

This string is used in `TwitterWebOAuthActivity` to fetch the Twitter request token.

```
@Override
protected OAuthToken doInBackground(Void... params) {
    // Fetch a one time use Request Token from Twitter
    return connectionFactory.getOAuthOperations().fetchRequestToken(getOAuthCallbackUrl(), null);
}
```

If you want to modify the callback URL for your own app, you need to make sure it is configured the same in the `AndroidManifest.xml` and `res/values/connect_settings.xml`.